# How to get values of dataframe that has characteres

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col' : [1,2, 10, np.nan, 'a'], 
                   'col2': ['a', 10, 30, 'c',50],
                   'col3': [1,2,3,4,5.0]})
```

How I obtein about the column col2 a new dataframe with has characters.
In this case
df_final = ['a', 'c']

I try  to verify if not number but this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`pandas.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) in this case by using a regex that does not match numbers. It should be noted that we need to set `na` argument to False because as per documentation

> Specifying na to be False instead of NaN replaces NaN values with
> False. If Series or Index does not contain NaN values the resultant
> dtype will be bool, otherwise, an object dtype.

```
df.loc[df['col2'].str.contains(r'[^0-9]', na=False, regex=True)]

   col col2  col3
0    1    a   1.0
3  NaN    c   4.0
```

Comment: And if  has 'col2': ['a', '10,0000.23'  , '30', 'c','50,300.45'].  How identify when the number has comma and dot separtator for decimal and miles. @Anoushiravan R

Comment: You can replace the regex with `r'[^0-9,.]'`. You see `[...]` contains a list of characters where we would like to match or not. If I put `^` between the brackets we exclude those characters. So now I just added `.` and `,` to be excluded.